# Best method to merge two sql tables toegether

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

So I have two tables.  One tracking a a persons location, and one that has the shifts of staff members.

Staff members have a staffId, location, start and end times, and cost of that shift.

People have an eventId, stayId, personId, location, start and end time.  A person will have an event with multiple stays.

What I am attempting to do is mesh these two tables together, so that I can accurately report the cost of each location stay, based on the duration of that stay multiplied by the associated cost of staff covering that location at that time.

The issues I have are:

1. Location stays do not align with staff shifts.  i.e. a person might  be in             location a between 1pm and 2pm, and four staff might be on shifts from 12:30 to   1:30, and two on from 1:30 till 5.
2. There are a lot of records.
3. Not all staff are paid the same

My current method is to expand both tables to have a record for every single minute.  So a stay that is between 1pm and 2pm will have 60 records, and a staff shift that goes for 5 hours will have 300 records.  I can then take all staff that are working on that location at that minute to get a minute value based on the cost  of each staff member divided by the duration of their shift, and apply that value to the corresponding record in the other table.

Techniques used:

1. I create a table with 50,000 numbers, since some stays can be quite
   long.
2. I take the staff table and join onto the numbers table to split each
   shift. Then group it together based on location and minute, with a
   staff count and minute cost.
3. The final step, and the one causing issues, is where I take the
   location table, join onto numbers, and also onto the modified staff
   table to produce a cost for that minute.  I also count the number of
   people in that location to account for staff covering multiple
   people.

I'm finding this process extremely slow as you can imagine, since my person table has about 500 million records when expanded to the minute level, and the staff table has about 35 million when the same thing is done.

Can people suggest a better method for me to use?

Sample data:
Locations

```
| EventId |  ID | Person | Loc |          Start         |         End
|  1      | 987 |  123   |  1  | May, 20 2015 07:00:00 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 
|  1      | 374 |  123   |  4  | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 
|  1      | 184 |  123   |  3  | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 
|  1      | 798 |  123   |  8  | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00
```

Staff

```
| Loc | StaffID | Cost |         Start         |         End
|  1  | 99      |  40  | May, 20 2015 04:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00 
|  1  | 15      |  85  | May, 20 2015 03:00:00 | May, 20 2015 5:00:00 
|  3  | 85      |  74  | May, 20 2015 18:00:00 | May, 20 2015 20:00:00 
|  4  | 10      |  36  | May, 20 2015 06:00:00 | May, 20 2015 14:00:00
```

Result

`| EventId |  ID | Person | Loc |          Start         |         End          | Cost
 |  1      | 987 |  123   |  1  | May, 20 2015 07:00:00 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | 45.50
 |  1      | 374 |  123   |  4  | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | 81.20
 |  1      | 184 |  123   |  3  | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | 95.00
 |  1      | 798 |  123   |  8  | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00 | 14.75`

SQL:
Numbers table

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (224) object_id  FROM sys.all_objects 
)
SELECT TOP (50000) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.object_id) 
INTO #numbers
FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS y 
ORDER BY n
```

Staff Table

```
SELECT 
    Location,
    ISNULL(SUM(ROUND(Cost/ CASE WHEN (DateDiff(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (DateDiff(MINUTE, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)) END, 5)),0) AS MinuteCost,
    Count(Name) AS StaffCount,
    RosterMinute = DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, StartDateTime) + n.n -1,     0) 
INTO #temp_StaffRoster
FROM dbo.StaffRoster
```

Grouping together, and where help is needed I think

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.FinalTable
    SELECT [EventId]
          ,[Id]
          ,[Start]
          ,[End]
          ,event.[Location]
          ,SUM(ISNULL(MinuteCost,1)/ISNULL(PeopleCount, 1)) AS Cost
          ,AVG(ISNULL(StaffCount,1)) AS AvgStaff
      FROM dbo.Events event WITH (NOLOCK) 
      INNER JOIN #numbers n ON n.n BETWEEN 0 AND  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, End)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp_StaffRoster staff WITH (NOLOCK) ON staff.Location= event.Location AND staff.RosterMinute = DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, Start) + n.n -1 ,     0)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Location], DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, Start) + n.n -1 ,     0) AS Mins, COUNT(Id) as PeopleCount
                       FROM dbo.Events WITH (NOLOCK) 
                       INNER JOIN #numbers n ON n.n BETWEEN 0 AND  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start, End)
                       GROUP BY [Location], DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, Start) + n.n -1 ,     0)
                       ) cap ON cap.Location= event.LocationAND cap.Mins = DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, Start) + n.n -1 ,     0)

      GROUP BY [EventId]
              ,[Id]
              ,[Start]
              ,[End]
              ,event.[Location]
```

**UPDATE**

So I have two tables.  One tracking a a persons location, and one that has the shifts of staff members with their cost.  I am attempting to consolidate the two tables to calculate the cost of each location stay.

Here is my method:

```
;;WITH stay AS
(
    SELECT TOP 650000
        StayId,
        Location,
        Start,
        End
    FROM stg_Stay
    WHERE Loction IS NOT NULL  -- Some locations don't currently have a matching shift location
    ORDER BY Location, ADTM
),
shift AS
(
    SELECT TOP 36000000
        Location,
        ShiftMinute,
        MinuteCost,
        StaffCount
    FROM stg_Shifts
    ORDER BY Location, ShiftMinute
)

SELECT 
    [StayId],
    SUM(MinuteCost) AS Cost,
    AVG(StaffCount) AS StaffCount
INTO newTable
FROM stay S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MinuteCost, StaffCount
                FROM shift R 
                WHERE R.Location = S.Location
                 AND R.ShiftMinute BETWEEN S.Start AND S.End 
            ) AS Shifts
GROUP BY [StayId]
```

This is where I'm at.

I've split the Shifts table into a minute by minute level since there is no clear alignment of shifts to stays.

stg_Stay contains more columns than needed for this operation.  stg_Shift is as shown.

Indexes used on stg_Shifts:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Shifts_Loc_Min
ON dbo.stg_Shifts (Location, ShiftMinute)
INCLUDE (MinuteCost, StaffCount);
```

on stg_Stay

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Stay_StayId ON dbo.stg_Stay (StayId);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Stay_Start_End_Loc ON dbo.stg_Stay (Location,Start,End);
```

Due to the fact that Shifts has ~36 million records and Stays has ~650k, what can I do to make this perform better?

Comment: It would help if you included in the question few sample rows for each table. Try to showcase all possible scenarios. Show how the final result should look like based on that sample data. Also, tell us approximate number of real rows in each table.

Comment: A general suggestion - when you expand your tables to the minute level, limit results to, say, one day only and process your data in batches, day after day. If you limit it to one day, do you still get 500M rows?

Comment: I wouldn't get 500M records if I limit it to a day, but that wouldn't help me much, as I'm trying to process a full year of data.  I've split it into four transactions (site specific) due to the transaction log filling up, but it's still taking a long time to process all the data.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to get the result you are expecting from the given data.

Comment: I added the sql i'm using

Comment: @Matt its a pretty easy problem but your description of it is very messy. How did you calculate a cost of 14,75 on location 8 when nobody had a shift there? Explain the rules of your calculation a bit more clearly and i think we are better able to actually give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't break down the rows by minutes.
2. Staging table may help if you can create fast relationship between them. i.e. the overlapped interval

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM Locations l
OUTER APPLY -- Assume a staff won't appear in different location in the same period of time, of course.
(
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(decimal(14,2), SUM(CostPerMinute * OverlappedMinutes)) AS ActualCost,
    COUNT(DISTINCT StaffId) AS StaffCount,
    SUM(OverlappedMinutes) AS StaffMinutes
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      *,
      -- Calculate overlapped time in minutes
      DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
        CASE WHEN StartTime > l.StartTime THEN StartTime ELSE l.StartTime END, -- Get greatest start time
        CASE WHEN EndTime > l.EndTime THEN l.EndTime ELSE EndTime END -- Get least end time
      ) AS OverlappedMinutes,
      Cost / DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) AS CostPerMinute
    FROM Staff 
    WHERE LocationId = l.LocationId 
      AND StartTime <= l.EndTime AND l.StartTime <= EndTime -- Match with overlapped time
  ) data
) StaffInLoc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf005/6)

Comment: ooooh, that looks interesting.  I'm about to head home, so I'll give it a shot tomorrow and report back.  6 minutes is the time to beat at the moment.

Comment: So without any indexes on the Staff table, this runs at the same pace as my current query.  So I can probably speed it up still!.  Next issue will be to run a query over this to determine the number of people in each location at a set time so I can spread the ActualCost over the PeopleCount.  This has given me much to think about thanks!  I'll close the question now.  Thanks again

Comment: @Matt Glad to see this helps. Note if a staff stay is less than a minute, this query will return 0 cost as this is written to be accurate to minute.

Answer (score 0):

Take below with a grain of salt since your naming is horrible.

Location should really be a Stay as i guess location is another table defining an single physical location.

Your Staff table is also badly named. Why not name it Shift. I would expect a staff table to contain stuff like Name, Phone etc. Where a Shift table can contain multiple shifts for the same Staff etc.

Second i think your missing a relation between the two tables.

If you join Location and Staff only on Location and overlapping date times i don't think it would make a whole lot of sense for what your trying to do. How do you know which staff is at any location for a given time? Onlything you can do with location and overlapping dates is assume a entry is in the location table relates to every staff who have a shift at that location within the timeframe. So look at the below more as an inspiration to solving your problems and how to find overlapping datetime intervals and less like an actual solution to your problem since i think your data and model is in a bad shape.

If i got it all wrong please provide Primary Keys and Foreign Keys on your tables and a better explanation.

Some dummy data

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Location
CREATE TABLE dbo.Location
(
StayId INT,
EventId INT,
PersonId INT,
LocationId INT,
StartTime DATETIME2(0),
EndTime DATETIME2(0)
)


INSERT INTO dbo.Location ( StayId ,EventId ,PersonId ,LocationId ,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 987 ,1 ,123 ,1 ,'2015-05-20T07:00:00','2015-05-20T08:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Location ( StayId ,EventId ,PersonId ,LocationId ,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 374 ,1 ,123 ,4 ,'2015-05-20T08:00:00','2015-05-20T10:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Location ( StayId ,EventId ,PersonId ,LocationId ,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 184 ,1 ,123 ,3 ,'2015-05-20T10:00:00','2015-05-20T11:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Location ( StayId ,EventId ,PersonId ,LocationId ,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 798 ,1 ,123 ,8 ,'2015-05-20T11:00:00','2015-05-20T12:00:00')

DROP TABLE dbo.Staff
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
StaffId INT,
Cost INT,
LocationId INT,
StartTime DATETIME2(0),
EndTime DATETIME2(0)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Staff ( StaffId ,Cost ,LocationId,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 99 ,40 ,1 ,'2015-05-20T04:00:00','2015-05-20T12:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Staff ( StaffId ,Cost ,LocationId,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 15 ,85 ,1 ,'2015-05-20T03:00:00','2015-05-20T05:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Staff ( StaffId ,Cost ,LocationId,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 85 ,74 ,3 ,'2015-05-20T18:00:00','2015-05-20T20:00:00')
INSERT INTO dbo.Staff ( StaffId ,Cost ,LocationId,StartTime ,EndTime)
VALUES  ( 10 ,36 ,4 ,'2015-05-20T06:00:00','2015-05-20T14:00:00')
```

Actual query

```
WITH OnLocation AS
(
    SELECT 
    L.StayId, L.EventId, L.LocationId, L.PersonId, S.Cost
    , IIF(L.StartTime > S.StartTime, L.StartTime, S.StartTime) AS OnLocationStartTime
    , IIF(L.EndTime < S.EndTime, L.EndTime, S.EndTime) AS OnLocationEndTime      
    FROM dbo.Location L
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Staff S
    ON S.LocationId = L.LocationId  -- TODO are you not missing a join condition on staffid
    -- Detects any overlaps between stays and shifts
    AND L.StartTime <= S.EndTime AND L.EndTime >= S.StartTime
)

SELECT 
*
, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.OnLocationStartTime, D.OnLocationEndTime) AS DurationMinutes
, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D.OnLocationStartTime, D.OnLocationEndTime) / 60.0 * Cost AS DurationCost
FROM OnLocation D
```

To get a summary you can take the query and add a GROUP BY for whatever your wan't to summarize.

Comment: Shifts and Stays are much better names, I agree.  I changed the names because they wouldn't make sense using the originals.  Shifts cover specific locations, so the link between location and time works.  I'll give your method a go and report back. Cheers

Comment: @Matt I still think your missing a join condition. Even if you have specific locations and time how would you determine the following cost. Two staff that have the same shift 9 PM to 10 PM at the same location, 1 staff arrives late so you have two stays one from 9 PM to 10 PM and one from 9:15 PM to 10 PM. Which staff arrived late? imagin that one cost 100 an hour and another 200? is the total cost then 100*1.0+200*0.75= 250 or is it 100*0.75+200*1.0=275. I think you need to know what staff at what shift were at which stay.

Comment: My shift table is already consolidated.  I used a similar process to break every shift down to a minute by minute level, and then grouped together on location and minute.  That way I account for shift crossovers and also staff paid at different rates.

Comment: My issues seem to be more about process rather than logic I think.  Basically I have a two tables ones with people in locations, and one with costs associated with those locations at certain times.  I need to mesh them together.  The only way I see that possible due to the inconsistency with times is to break everything down to the minute level and join together.  The issue with this is I'm experiencing around 500M records, and my database is shitting itself.

Comment: @Matt i dont understand why you insist on breaking down shifts and stays into minutes? Don't you simply want the overlapping intervals?

Comment: I realise now I can keep stays together, but fairly sure I need to break down shifts since there is no consistency between how many staff are on, how much each staff member gets paid, and how many people are in a location at a specific time.  By breaking down the shifts into a cost per minute for each location, it's far easier to get an accurate cost for each stay segment.  Stays can also last anywhere from a few minutes to a few months.   I believe I may have partially solved my issue by using better keys on the shifts table.  It now completes in 6 minutes.  I'd like to do better though.